# Return string how to fix cannot return value referencing temporary value

Tags: string, logging, rust, lifetime

I want to filter the `msg` in `debug_args` function before returning:

```
pub trait MyLog {
    fn debug_args(&self) -> &dyn std::fmt::Debug;
}

pub struct TracingMyLog<'a> {
    record: &'a tracing::Event<'a>,
    fields: Map<String, Value>,
    message: Option<String>,
}

impl<'a> MyLog for TracingMyLog<'a> {
    fn debug_args(&self) -> &dyn std::fmt::Debug {
        if let Some(msg) = self.message.as_ref() {
            msg
        } else {
            &""
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use Regex on msg but I get this error:
`cannot return value referencing temporary value returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`.

```
fn regex_msg(str: &String) -> String {
    let re = Regex::new("sig: \"0x[a-fA-F0-9]+\"").unwrap();
    re.replace_all(&str, "sig: \"***filtered***\"")
        .to_string()
}

    fn debug_args(&self) -> &dyn std::fmt::Debug {
        if let Some(msg) = self.message.as_ref() {
            &regex_msg(msg)
        } else {
            &""
        }
    }
```

I understand that this is trying to return a reference to a value that is local to the function and once the function returns, its local values are dropped and any references to them would dangle.

I also tried cloning the `msg` string in a new function & returning a reference to it which is also not allowed by the compiler.

Finally, I think a workaround exists with `Cow<str>` but I don't wanna use it.

Q. How can I achieve the filtering operation on the above `msg` without changing the function signature if possible?

Comment: Try returning `&dyn std::fmt::Debug + 'a`. This will tell the compiler that returned trait object has lifetime tied to lifetime `'a`.

Comment: The `String` has to live somewhere. You could store the filtered debug`String` in a field on your struct and return a reference to it. However, it would be better in this case to just return the `String` itself. This means returning `impl Debug` rather than `&dyn Debug`, but that's already ok since every `&dyn Debug` is also `impl Debug`

Comment: Using `Cow` is fine. Why don't you want to do it? Alternatively, you can return `Box<dyn Debug>`.

Comment: @JMAA You can't return `impl Debug` in a trait (although I think this will be stabilized soon).

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Error: Syntax Error: ambiguous `+` in a type

Answer (score 0):

A returned `&str` always has a lifetime.  So if you want to return a `&str` that references data you created in the function, you have, in general, two possibilities:

1. Store the data in the `self` object, and return a reference with the lifetime of `&self`.
2. Leak the data and return a `&'static str` (in general, don't do this!  It may be ok in setup code where the lifetime of the data really should be the lifetime of the program, but that don't seem to be the case in the question).

Maybe you could apply the regex when storing message (assuming `self.message` is a private field)?

Or, as a different variation of the theme, you could store `message` not as an `Option<String>` but as an `Option<MySecretString>`, return a reference to that directly and put the regex handling in the `Debug` impl of `MySecretString`.  I think this is what I would do.

Comment: Please don't leak the data... Technically this would work around the problem, but at the cost of a (pretty unidiomatic) memory leak.

Comment: @JMAA, true.  I added a note about avoiding to leak the data and in which cases it may still be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, this is how I'd approach this:

If you really cannot change the signature of `debug_args`, then I'd store the filtered message in a `String` member of your struct so you can return a reference to it. However, `MyLog` looks like your own trait, so I'd really advise you change that instead.

I would change `MyLog` to look like this:

```rust
pub trait MyLog<'a, T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug + 'a
{
    fn debug_args(&'a self) -> T;
}
```

This is much more idiomatic than returning a `&dyn Trait` (which has its place, but isn't necessary here from what I can see). This is basically saying "you can implement this to return any type, so long as that type implements `Debug` and lives at least as long as the `&self` you borrow".

Then you can implement it like this:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b> MyLog<'a, Cow<'a, str>> for TracingMyLog<'b>
{
    fn debug_args(&self) -> Cow<str> {
        if let Some(msg) = self.message.as_ref() {
            regex_msg(msg)
        } else {
            "".into()
        }
    }
}

fn regex_msg(msg: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    let re = Regex::new("sig: \"0x[a-fA-F0-9]+\"").unwrap();
    re.replace_all(msg, "sig: \"***filtered***\"")
}
```

This is saying "logging this returns a `Cow<str>`: it might borrow a string from `&self` or it might not".

Additionally, I've fixed up the signature of `regex_msg`. First, you should always prefer `&str` over `&String` as a parameter (it's more flexible, more idiomatic, and very very rarely do you actually care whether the data is stored in a `String` or, for example, a literal). Second, it now returns `Cow<str>` just like `Regex::replace_all`, avoiding an extra allocation if no matches were found. Finally, please don't name a variable `str`: it will probably confuse readers of your code as it's a built-in type.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78f7ac7b9adcb04f0ee0eafac2b90799)

---

A very slightly simpler version would be to instead do

```rust
pub trait MyLog<T>
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug
{
    fn debug_args(&self) -> T;
}
```

But now you couldn't return a `Cow<'_, str>` (since there's no link between the lifetime of `&self` and `T`), so you'd have to `impl MyLog<String>` and just return an allocated `String`. For the sake of a couple of lifetime annotations I think that avoiding the allocation is totally worth it.